VM Virtualbox: can only login on VPN client on VM when VM's firewall is off. How to add an exception to the VM's FIrewall?
I need a Windows OS for work in which I have full control. I have a computer with Ubuntu and from there I am running a Windows 10 VM through Oracle's VM VirtualBox.
My work requires me to use a VPN client on the Windows VM. I have noticed I am only able to login on this VPN client on the VM when it's Firewall from Windows Defender has been turned off.
Login is not possible when this Firewall on the VM is on. Can I add an exception to the Firewall so it allows (in/out?)bound connections of the VPN client.
(I am a total n00b when it comes to VM's)

Your question has nothing to do with VMs. The same happens with a normal installation.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@John thank you. Can you explain what exactly changed. As I understand the connection is now directly with the router instead of through my Ubuntu machine? Why does that solve the problem?
